# Poster.png slips by 30px

Tags: mediaelement.js

Here: http://waldvisuals.com/video/

It's in Wordpress. Here's the code on the page:

#### Showreel

[video mp4="http://waldvisuals.com/wp-content/uploads/video/Showreel.mp4" ogg="http://waldvisuals.com/wp-content/uploads/video/Showreel.ogv" webm="http://waldvisuals.com/wp-content/uploads/video/Showreel.webm" poster="http://waldvisuals.com/wp-content/uploads/video/poster.png" preload="true" width="640" height="360"]

Doesn't slip on an iPad, but does on a Mac via Safari and Firefox. Any fixes?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but if someone comes across this...
I had the same problem. It was because the template created a 1em margin around every IMG in posts.
I solved this by replacing in **mediaelement-and-player.min.js** and **ediaelement-and-player.js**

the term

```
<img width="100%" height="100%" />
```

with

```
<img width="100%" height="100%" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;" />
```